# Error while installing python modules on ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, module

I am having trouble with installation of 3 python modules on ubuntu:

1. openai
2. speech_recognition
3. win32com.client

It is giving me the error after after the command sudo apt install python3-module_name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKrQ5.png)

I was trying to get the modules installed

Comment: Have you tried using `pip` the python package installer?

Comment: That's not how you install python packages. `python3-whatever` is for system packages and is requires for some stuff that has system bindings or for some reason is not included in most basic python installation. Just install `apt install python3-dev` to have development headers to build stuff, then just `pip install whatever` for those packages. Also, why do you want to install win32com on linux? that doesn't make sense

Comment: I just did what you told me, but it's still the same error..